# Save input and ask to use it again when restarting program

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, input, passwords

How can I save a user's input and ask them if they want to use it again when restarting the program, so they don't have to enter the same thing every time they close the program?

Answer (score 0):

You should store the data in some **DB** or **JSON** file, there is no way to save input data stored in a variable after closing the program.

Comment: Thank you. My question now is, how can I make the program copy the input that has been saved in the file and enter it automatically

Comment: If you decide to go with JSON see these [`open`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_open.asp), [`write_in_json`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-and-writing-json-to-a-file-in-python/) ... If you are planning to go with some DB SQLi is the lightest and preferrable to use for small data [`SQLiPython`](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/) .. For more complex data storing you should go with [`Postgres`](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/usage.html)

Comment: @Sen0a Go ahead and Google that, its not too hard to learn these things, but they aren't S.O. questions...

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this. It's save user input data to `config.py` module, so you can use it anywhere.

```
import os

user_input = None  
if os.path.exists('config.py'): #check if config file exist
    ask = input("Do you want use previous data? (yes/no)")
    if ask == 'no':
        user_input = input("Some things...")
    elif ask == 'yes':
        import config
        user_input = config.last_input  # take last value of input from config file
    else:
        print("Wrong command, please anserw yes or no.")
else:
    user_input = input("Some things...")

print(user_input)

# save input
with open("config.py", "w+") as file:
    file.write(f"last_input = {user_input}")
```

It's easy way, not needed to use json or ini files. You can just copy&paste this, will work.